# How does filter work in WordPress data table?

Tags: wordpress

I am customizing `Awesome Support` plugin to meet my needs. There is a filter option of `all tickets`. When I filter against ID it does not works properly. [image]

I set an ID which actually does  not exist. So it should show empty table. all previous data is being shown. But when I set an ID which actually exist it work fine:
[image]

I go through the code of the plugin. found the following lines which is responsible(may be):

public function set_filtering_query_var( $query ) {

```
global $post_type;

if ( 'ticket' !== $post_type
    || ! $query->is_main_query()
    || empty ($_GET[ 'id' ])
) {
    return;
}

$fields = $this->get_custom_fields();

foreach( $fields as $key => $value ) {
    if ( 'id' !== $key && $value[ 'args' ][ 'filterable' ] ) {
        $query->query[ $key ] = '';
        $query->set( $key, '');
    }
}

$query->query[ 'post_status' ] = '';
$query->set( 'post_status', '');

$query->query[ 'filter-by-date' ] = '';
$query->set( 'filter-by-date', '');
// echo '<pre>';print_r($query);
```

}

But can't figure out why its happening for an ID which is not exist.
 Any idea? please refer any study link. I know I am asking like nonsense, but this problem makes me cry. Thanks for your time.

N.B: url structure while filtering: `wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=all&post_type=ticket&id=574603956219986&filter_action=Filter&s&paged=1&action2=-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code

`if (!empty ($_GET[ 'id' ])) {
    $id = esc_attr( $_GET['id'] );
    $query->set('post__in', array($id));
}`